# python form handle

Tags: python

How can I handle html form input (array) like the one below in Python:

```
<input type='hidden' name='a[]' value='some_value'>
```

The following doesn't work:

```
a_value = form["a"].value
```

Please help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What framework or system are you using for processing the form submission? CGI, mod_python, WSGI, Django, Werkzeug, etc.?

Comment: I'm using CGI. In fact a new <input type='hidden'...> is added to the page with jquery on every click of an add button, like this: $('#Add-btn').live('click',function() { ... $("#tabName tr:last").before("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='a' value='" + a + "'>" + a  + "</td></tr>");});

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at http://formencode.org/Validator.html#http-html-form-input

input name / value

```
names-1.fname   John
names-1.lname   Doe
names-2.fname   Jane
names-2.lname   Brown
```

will be parsed into

```
{'names': [
       {'fname': "John", 'lname': "Doe"},
       {'fname': "Jane", 'lname': 'Brown'},
```

UPDATE:

In your case `<input type="hidden" name="item.a" value="5" />` will be parsed into `item['a'] = 5`